# "Import Error: NumPy not found" when importing wx.lib.py

Tags: python, numpy, plot, wxpython

import wx.lib.plot

When I try importing wx.lib.py it gives me the following error:

> ImportError: NumPy not found.
>
> This module requires the NumPy module, which could not be imported.  It probably is not installed (it's not part of the standard Python distribution). See the Numeric Python site ([Link](https://numpy.org)) for information on downloading source or binaries.

However, I had previously installed it on the command prompt and it shows as

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/[my name]/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this issue board:  https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/565

The error happens because wxpython uses numpy.oldnumeric which has been removed in numpy 1.9:

```
# Needs NumPy 
try:
    import numpy.oldnumeric as _Numeric 
except:
    msg= """
    This module requires the NumPy module, which could not be
    imported.  It probably is not installed (it's not part of the
    standard Python distribution). See the Numeric Python site
    (http://numpy.scipy.org) for information on downloading source or
    binaries."""
    raise ImportError, "NumPy not found.\n" + msg
```

Comment: Agree totally.  It's uninformative, misleading, and sends the user in a wrong direction.  Honestly, I stopped working with WX.  I now just work in Jupyter and use widgets!  That community is very active and lots of features.

Comment: Only ancient versions of wxPython need ancient versions of numpy, `wx.lib.plot` has been updated a few times since then.

Comment: Upgrade your wxPython and this should go away